# Adding a line connecting all div

Tags: html, css

I am having multiple circles and trying to connect all the circle divs with a line. So, it should be two lines connecting first and second & second and third. The line should be aligned to the circle center.

I am trying to make the row to be relative and putting a `hr` with absolute position, but it turned out not working well.

I am not sure the best way to implement it to work it in responsive

```css
.circle {
  width: 49%;
  padding-bottom: 49%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container .row .col-xs-4 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  
  </div>
  
    
  </div>
 
 
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this; http://i.imgur.com/XrwxXHQ.png?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande : Yes. Note that the border is just for me to see any margins/paddings if any.

Comment: If that's what you need, I'll post the answer.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande: Thanks. Looking forward to it. The issues I am having is to make it responsive. Hopefully yours solved it. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your rectangles have a 33.3% width each, add a `position: absolute` div with `width: 66.6%`, and place it in the middle. (If you don't want pixel perfect, 50% top will do, since the line will be 1px)

```css
.circle {
  width: 49%;
  padding-bottom: 49%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container .row .col-xs-4 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}

.container { position: relative; }
.line { 
  width: 66.6%; 
  height: 1px; 
  background: #000; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 16.65%; /* Half the circle's width **/; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="line"></div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Oops. I don't need the last part. It should be in between the circles only. My bad.

Comment: That's why I asked you ;) If you don't want the last part, let me fix it, It'll be a little trickier :P You mind javascript, or pure css?

Comment: My bad bro. Sorry. At first I thought just CSS. But for me it will be super tricky. So js should be fine. Most users have it enabled.

Comment: Done! Since your rectangles are 33.3%, just put 66.6% to the line, instead of 100%

Comment: Yeah. That is equivalent to col-8!

Comment: Thanks! Now another issue, the circle will be centered. So I will make it display: inline block and let the parent to text-align to be center. How can I know how much to shift the line as well to the right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>  
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

```
.circle {
  width: 49%;
  padding-bottom: 49%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.container .row .col-xs-4 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

 .col-xs-4 {
   position: relative;
 } 
 .line {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```